# How to remove the cart link from homepage of magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

I am trying to remove the cart link and icon from the homepage of Magento 2. But making any changes to `default.xml` of `Magento_Theme` is removing the cart icon from every page, as expected. Is there any way of removing it *just* from the homepage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do in your custom theme or in the custom module.

Following code is from my custom module.
**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Here, Anshu is the namespace and Custom is the module name.

Basically, what you need to change in your code is that instead of using the `default.xml`, you need to use `cms_index_index.xml`

You can go through https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html for more information.

Comment: this will remove link / block from all cms pages, isn't so ?

Comment: @NaveedAsim No, it is will remove only for homepage. cms_index_index.xml is used for home page only. cms_page_view.xml is used for other cms pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to hide the icon from homepage, you can manage it using the stylesheets by using the below style

```
.cms-home .minicart-wrapper{display:none;}
```